# How do I get my code to retrieve an environment variable on Linux (Ubuntu)?

Tags: asp.net-core, environment-variables

I have an ASP.Net Core app running on Ubuntu on the server (I dev on Windows). In a block of code, I use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("API_KEY"));`. In dev, the key is retrieved succesfully. However, when I publish the code to the server, the key cannot be retrieved for some reason. `API_KEY` ends up being null.

Note: The ASP.NET Core runtimes are both the same versions (5.0 preview 7) on dev and prod and yes, I have the environment variable setup on the server and can `printenv` it out. When I plug in the actual key into the app rather than use an environment variable name, my app works as I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you have to manually put that setting in your applications "configuration" section. When running on you local machine, it will pull from the `local.settings.json`, but on the server running in `Release` mode, it will pull from the server-side config. That config is located here:

[image: server side config]

This is done because your local environment should be running different (safe) settings than something running live on a server.

If you accidentally commit your code to a repo and that `local.settings.json` goes along with it, someone who gets in to your repo won't be able to get critical data.

Comment: I am not using config files to store my secrets. I am using environment variables, which are being retrieved on Windows (Dev) and not Ubuntu (Prod).